# SNMPv3 Net-SNMP generate_Ku() function - how does it creates the hash?

Tags: authentication, snmp, net-snmp

I'm working on my own SNMPv3 app using the Net-SNMP open source library, providing netsnmp_session with the authentication key with the following (a bit shortend) code. This works as expected, communication with the agent is fine.

```
opensession()
{
    netsnmp_session* pSnmpSession = netsnmp_malloc_session();

    pSnmpSession->version = = SNMP_VERSION_3;
    
    pSnmpSession->securityAuthProtoLen = OID_LENGTH(usmHMACMD5AuthProtocol);
    pSnmpSession->securityAuthProto = snmp_duplicate_objid(usmHMACMD5AuthProtocol, OID_LENGTH(usmHMACMD5AuthProtocol));

    string m_v3authKey("mysecretpassword");

    pSnmpSession->securityAuthKeyLen = sizeof(pSnmpSession->securityAuthKey);
    if (generate_Ku(pSnmpSession->securityAuthProto,
        (u_int)pSnmpSession->securityAuthProtoLen,
        (const u_char*)m_v3authKey.c_str(), m_v3authKey.size(),
        pSnmpSession->securityAuthKey,
        &pSnmpSession->securityAuthKeyLen) != SNMPERR_SUCCESS)
    {
        print("Error!");
    }

    snmp_open_ex(pSnmpSession, ...);
    
}
```

After doing a little investigation and debugging, I'm wondering about the way, generate_Ku transforms the plain password ("mysecretpassword") to the hash.

It turns out, this function builds the hash from filling up 16k (!) times a buffer of 64 Bytes with the plain password, which gives a total of 1MB data to build the authentication key hash from.

With the following code using OpenSSL, I'm will get the same hashes.

```
bool generate_openssl_Ku(byte* text, unsigned int textlen, byte* hash, unsigned int* phashlen)
{
    byte hashblock[64];
    int repeat = 1024 * 1024;   //(!!)
    int count = 0;

    EVP_MD_CTX* ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();

    EVP_DigestInit(ctx, EVP_md5());

    while (repeat > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(hashblock); i++)
        {
            hashblock[i] = text[count % textlen];
            count++;
        }
        EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx, hashblock, sizeof(hashblock));
        repeat -= sizeof(hashblock);
    }

    /* alternative 
    byte* megablock = (byte*)malloc(repeat);

    for (count = 0; count < repeat; count++)
    {
        megablock[count] = text[count % textlen];
    }
    EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx, megablock, repeat);

    free(megablock);
    */

    EVP_DigestFinal(ctx, hash, phashlen);

    EVP_MD_CTX_free(ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

So I appreciate some deeper insights or explanation for this algorithm. Where, in which RFC, is this specified? Why exactly 1024 * 1024 bytes data are needed to build the hash?